# Is it possible to overload an entire interface based on the type of a generic type?

Tags: typescript

If I have an interface with a generic type, is it possible to overload the whole interface based on the type parameter provided such that I can use a different interface for a specific type?

Right now I am using using conditional logic on the properties to determine what `T` is but that's getting impossible to read

e.g.

```
interface Foo<T> {}

interface Foo<string> {
   foo(): void
   bar(): void
}

interface Foo<number> {
   bar(): void
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with generic `interface` declarations, but you can use conditional types to accomplish the same behavior

```
type Foo<T> = 
  T extends string ? {
  foo(): void;
  bar(): void;
 } :
  T extends number ? {
  bar(): void;
 } :
 { }
```